# How to display one item in an array each week

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, time

I am trying to create a memory verse a week program. I have code to display the item, but only with a delay for however long I want the code to wait before it changes items. How can I display one item at a time in an array for one week then go on to the next item without waiting a week for the delay? This is what I have now:

```
<p id="wfm"></p>

var mind = [];
var i = 0;

var wfmind = document.getElementById('wfm');
function next_verse() {

     wfmind.innerHTML = mind[i % mind.length];
     i += 1;

}
setInterval(next_verse, 1000);
```

Comment: Save the time that you showed the item, and the array index, in `localStorage`. Then when they come back, get the time from local storage, compare it to the current time, and if it's more than a week increment the index and show the next time.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You want to change the delay (currently 1000ms, or 1 second) to 1 week, but not actually wait 1 week? That seems contradictory. For debugging purposes you'd obviously want to keep it at 1 second or something in that vicinity.

Comment: @Extragorey I think he means he doesn't want to use `setInterval()` to wait a week. Probably because the user isn't going to keep the page open the whole time, so it won't work.

Comment: @Barmar Ah I see, in that case finding the current week from the calendar like you suggested seems like the way to go.

Comment: @axelduch Perhaps, although I suspect if you're just changing a message once a week, the precise time isn't really that important.

Comment: @axelduch Also, my original suggestion doesn't even depend on the time of day. It just measures if the absolute time since the previous change is more than 1 week.

Comment: I'm going to try dividing the number of weeks in a year by the number of milliseconds in a math function and iterating it that way. If I use Math.ceil it will round up. Maybe I am too tired and need to sleep on it. Then try it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the current time as the index, which counts from 1970 rather than the arbitrary time the user entered the site.

As of writing, the current timestamp is 1493684749486.

```
var d = new Date();
// +d === 1493684749486
```

To convert the current timestamp into an array index, you need to know the number of milliseconds in a week (1000*60*60*24*7), then figure out how many weeks have passed since 1970.

```
var index = Math.floor(+d / (1000*60*60*24*7));
// 2469 weeks have passed since 1970
// output `mind[index]` now.
```

For the sake of the answer here, I'm going to assume you want to change the item on Friday at 9am. The next closest Friday at 9am is 1494000000000.

```
d.setMilliseconds(0);
d.setSeconds(0);
d.setMinutes(0);
d.setHours(9);
d.setDate(d.getDate() + (7 + 5 - d.getDay()) % 7); // How many days away is Friday from Monday? Add that to the current date.
```

That is 315250514 milliseconds away. You'll setTimeout this long to kick off the next change.

When the item changes, kick off a new timeout for the following change. This is preferred over setInterval.

```
function displayNextItem() {
  var d = new Date();
  var timestamp = +d;
  var index = Math.floor(timestamp / (1000*60*60*24*7));
  wfmind.innerHTML = mind[index % mind.length];

  d.setMilliseconds(0);
  d.setSeconds(0);
  d.setMinutes(0);
  d.setHours(9);
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (7 + 5 - d.getDay()) % 7); // How many days away is Friday from Monday? Add that to the current date.

  setTimeout(displayNextItem, +d - timestamp);
}
displayNextItem();
```

Comment: Thank you!! I think we might have it!! I will check it next week and let you know.